# Solving PDE via Fourier Transform & Uniqueness

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, heat-equation

When a PDE is solved via Fourier transform, is there already a uniqueness assertion that comes for free?

For example, if we Fourier the heat equation
 \begin{align}
\partial_t u(x,t) &= \Delta u(x,t)\\
u(x,0) &= u^0(x)
\end{align} 
to get in Fourier space (assuming $u^0 \in L^1$)
\begin{align}
\partial_t\hat{u}(\xi,t) &= -|\xi|^2\hat{u}(\xi,t)\\
\hat{u}(\xi,0) &= \hat{u^0}(\xi)
\end{align}
we know that the Fourier equation has a unique solution $\hat{u}(\xi,t) = e^{-t|\xi|^2} \hat{u^0}(\xi)$.

I suppose my question is: If the Fourier transform of a PDE (not just the heat equation) admits a unique solution, does this mean that when we Fourier back, the solution we get is unique?
And, in what sense is the solution unique (in $L^1$?).

Comment: You are, at the very least, assuming that $u$ is a temperate distribution in the variables that you are Fourier transforming.